# In-memory python card game / no database

Tags: python, uwsgi

I want to run a python card game using uwsgi/nginx on the server. It is a pain to learn uwsgi on the internet, hence my question here:

How can I run a python app on the server and read/update my objects when some request comes in? I don't want to model my game across database tables. Is this even possible?

All tutorials point to this example file

```
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return "Hello world!"
```

But inside application function I can't reference any previously defined variables.
What I wan't is:

```
i = 0
def application(env, start_response):
    i = i + 1
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return "Counter: " + str(i)
```

And as a result having i increment every time a request comes in.

I wrote hundreds of lines of game assuming I'll be able to do this much... but I've hit the wall. Any help would save me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `global i` before you use it. But this may or may not work as you expect, depending on your uwsgi configuration - do you have a spawn a pool of processes, use threading, or enable restarts? The `global` trick will work only as long as you have only one process running and as long as it doesn't get recycled between requests. And that process needs to be spawned on its own preferably - something like `paste` may be easier to configure to work the way you want.

Comment: Thank you. This worked, but revealed an entire new problem. As I keep refreshing the page results come: 1.. 1.. 3.. 5.. 1.. 10 I assume this is about multithreading or something...

Answer (score 0):

I believe each request handler is a separate worker process. You may be able to use a shared memory area for this:

https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi-docs/blob/master/SharedArea.rst

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. This is a whole new area for me but I have no choice but to explore it.